# Groovy Script error No such property: customerId for class

Tags: groovy

While executing the script I am getting error i.e groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: customerId for class

script is

```groovy
import org.w3c.dom.Node
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList
NodeList nodes = employeeServiceResponse.getFirstChild().getChildNodes()
String firstName = null
String lastName = null
for (int i = 0 i < nodes.getLength() i++) {
  Node node = nodes.item(i)
  if ("firstName".equals(node.getLocalName()))
    firstName = node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
  else if ("lastName".equals(node.getLocalName()))
    lastName = node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
}
if (firstName != null && lastName != null){
  println 'Found employee: ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName
  discountPercent = 10
  return true
} else {
  println 'Employee not found: ' + customerId
  discountPercent = 0
  return false
}
```

I am new to groovy scripting can any one help me please. The script parse the data.

Comment: Can you give some example xml?  How are you creating `employeeServiceResponse`?

Comment: <GetEmployee> <sapId> customerId </sapId> </GetEmployee>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote (last line) :

```
println 'Employee not found: ' + customerId
```

But `customerId` is not defined in this script. As you are looking for any employee in your script, you should just write :

```
println 'Employee not found'
```